# Incomplete escape \x at position

Tags: python, string, format, hex

I'm working with regexes on byte strings, that is regexes like

```
re.compile(b'\x01\x02')
```

Some characters which correspond to, for instance, letters, are automatically formatted. For example `x=b'\x50'`, then x will be equal to `'`, instead of keeping the `\x50` format.

I would like to be able to force the `\x##` format since it's causing problems further down the line, especially due to the `\` character.

For instance, if you try to execute

`re.compile(b'\\x')`

This should simply be the equivalent of `b'\x5c\x78'`, yet the regex breaks and says `incomplete escape \x at position 0`.

Comment: What problems? `b'\x50'` and `b'P'` (not `b"'"`) produce *exactly* the same `bytes` object.

Comment: @chepner I've added the example

Comment: It is equivalent; *both* produce the same error, because the regular-expression parser itself processes the `\x` sequence resulting from either literal.

Comment: Yes I just got to the same conclusion when after adding the edit, thanks for pushing it out of me! Feel free to post it as answer to get the cookies

Comment: Are you trying to escape the backslash to literally match the 2 characters? then `rb"\\x"` is likely what you want.